# CSS Floating Divs and Footer?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

[image]

So like you see, two floating divs at the top and a solid div at the bottom. But the solid div (footer) hides under the two floating divs.

How can I make it so it stays under the two floating divs and not in them like on the imgur?

```
.left {
  float:left;
  width:300px;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  width:300px;
}
.footer {
  width:600px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear:both;` to the footer rules.

```
.footer {
  width:600px;
  clear:both;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

just add clear:both; to your .footer in css to clear the floats.

for more info see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1wz2bud1/

```
.footer {
  width:600px;
  clear: both; 
}
```